# Reconstruct type after narrowing union subkey

Tags: typescript

Given a generated type from a DB where a key is a union of several types, I want to construct a type that contains only a subset of the union. I extracted the desired types from the union - how do I reconstruct the base type? or should I use a different approach?

```js
// This is an example, I don't have control of this type; it's generated and
// therefore I can't rewrite this in a composable way.
type _GeneratedPersonType = {
  age: number;
  name: string;
  profession: {
    type: "doctor"
  } | {
    type: "actor"
  } | {
    type: "magician"
  }
}

type Profession = _GeneratedPersonType["profession"];
type ActorProfession = Extract<Profession, { type: "actor" }>
type MagicianProfession = Extract<Profession, { type: "magician" }>

// this DOES NOT WORK as written, but I want it to be
// { ..., profession: ActorProfession | MagicianProfession }
type ActorOrMagician = _GeneratedPersonType & ActorProfession & MagicianProfession;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```ts
type ActorOrMagician = _GeneratedPersonType & { profession: ActorProfession | MagicianProfession }
```

---

TypeScript has [*intersection types*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types); an intersection type is assignable to all of its constituent types.

For example, the intersection of two object types will create an object type that has all the members of both those types:

```ts
type A = { a: number }
type B = { b: string }
type C = A & B
//   ^? { a: number; b: string }
```

You have actually attempted to use this, but not quite correctly.

```
type ActorOrMagician = _GeneratedPersonType & ActorProfession & MagicianProfession;
```

You are attempting to intersect both of the extracted `profession` types with the root type *and with each other*. As they are incompatible, the result is `never`*.

* The types are `{ type: "actor" }` and `{ type: "magician" }`. A type cannot be assignable to both `"actor"` and `"magician"`, so intersecting these produces `{ type: never }`. TypeScript then simplifies this "impossible type" to `never`.

Even if this was correct, there is another issue: you are intersecting the profession types directly with the root type. This will add the `type` property to the root of the new type, not add objects to the `profession` property.

So what you need to do is (A) use a union of the wanted professions and (B) use the correct structure.
The result is this:

```ts
type ActorOrMagician = _GeneratedPersonType & { profession: ActorProfession | MagicianProfession }
```

You can see I am using the **union** of `ActorProfession` and `MagicianProfession`, and putting them in an object with **the same structure as `_GeneratedPersonType`**.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA+g4hAdhATgQ2BAJgBVQZwHtEAVcaAXigG8AoKKNAcwgC4pEBXAWwCNV6HNNzZR8wFAEtETQWBSEAZhHz5JxVoIYAfGlFCR2AIiyEAxsEIojUAL5aou6vvLG0FqzfsMdeg6KNuZkkzSTREL1p7Wn8oHAVlVXVEKCp4JFQMbDwUIlJyAG0jeSUVNWIjAF0Y8igAQQ8UeNKk4lSoAFEADwl3YAAeZsTyxAAaP1coIz7POwA+GsgoAFlg0PChsuT27t6LQYSt4nHnf2MgphCwiPnaRegGyxQAeRRVy-WUtIRkdExcAjEMhLABkNDkh1aiHYjysmyhjhWa2u8JGUTusQAypJuGAADaSRQgfokObtZwFADSUGkUAA1hAQEooCRKuwSFTKnYoGDOIg6YhCAB3RD3fTtbG4glE-qwl5vZHhBYAemVPgAegB+WhAA)

---

As I noted before, you don't need to omit the `profession` property from `_GeneratedPersonType` first: that is the job of the intersection.
Intersections create a type that is assignable to all of the constituent types, so the resulting type will be at least as "narrow" as the "narrowest" type included.

You can see how this works, going from a simple case:

```ts
type Fruits = "apples" | "oranges" | "bananas"
type ApplesAndOranges = "apples" | "oranges"
type t1 = Fruits & ApplesAndOranges
//   ^? "apples" | "oranges"
// "bananas" is not assignable to "apples" | "oranges", so it is excluded.
```

You can extrapolate this to your case:

```ts
type PersonType = {
  profession:
    | { type: "doctor" }
    | { type: "actor" }
    | { type: "magician" }
}

type t1 = PersonType & {
  profession: { type: "actor" } | { type: "magician" }
}

// We can look at just that `profession` property:

type Professions = 
  | { type: "doctor" }
  | { type: "actor" }
  | { type: "magician" }

type t2 = Professions & ({ type: "actor" } | { type: "magician" })
//   ^? { type: "actor" } | { type: "magician" }
// { type: "doctor" } is not assignable to { type: "actor" } | { type: "magician" }, so it is excluded.

// Therefore:
// t1 = {
//   profession:
//     | { type: "actor" }
//     | { type: "magician" }
// }
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the thorough answer and examples.

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, it can be useful to omit the key that needs to be modified and then add a modified version with an intersection:

```ts
type ActorOrMagician = Omit<_GeneratedPersonType, 'profession'> & {
  profession: ActorProfession | MagicianProfession
}
```

Comment: You don't need to omit the key in this case. You can just do the intersection.